# Exercism Clojure exercise

Tags: clojure

I am learning clojure with Exercism and I'm having a bit of trouble finishing the last section of the lasagna problem.

Heres the instruction - Define the total-time function that takes two arguments: the first argument is the number of layers you added to the lasagna, and the second argument is the number of minutes the lasagna has been in the oven. The function should return how many minutes in total you've worked on cooking the lasagna, which is the sum of the preparation time in minutes, and the time in minutes the lasagna has spent in the oven at the moment.

here's my code thats giving me trouble:

```
(defn prep-time [num-layers]
  (* times-two num-layers))

(def sum (prep-time times-two))

(defn total-time [num-layers actual-time]
  (def test1 (prep-time num-layers))
  (+ test1 actual-time))

(def finished (total-time test1 prep-time))
```

Im getting an error saying:

```
`(defn prep-time [num-layers] 
11:   (* times-two num-layers))    
        ^--sci.impl.fns$fun$arity_1__1213 cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`
```

why would I be getting this error and what dose it mean?

Comment: Using `def` not on top level is a no-no (it modifies the namespace) - it's `test1` inside `total-time` . Take a look at `let` instead; also relying on that `(def test1 ...)` again outside of the other `defn` is bad too. Also could you please improve on the question and state the actual problem you are facing? Do you get an exception or some assertion?

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should be about a _specific technical problem_ you encountered. "Solve this assignment" is too broad to be on-topic here. Granted, there are specific technical problems in your code, but it's your job to identify one, build a [mre] reproducing it, and ask about just that problem.

Comment: That's my bad thank you, ill make sure to clarify my problem more clearly next time. But the problem I was facing was when I ran my code I would get an error saying -      
  `(defn prep-time [num-layers]
11:   (* times-two num-layers))
      ^--- sci.impl.fns$fun$arity_1__1213 cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`                        wasn't sure why i was getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question about the casting error this is because `times-two` is a function, but you are passing it to `*` which expects its parameters to be numbers.

You don't specify how you define `times-two`, but I suspect you meant that line to be `(times-two num-layers)` — or simply `(* 2 num-layers)`.

However, as [Martin Půda points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69378900/440294), using `def` inside `defn` is almost certainly a misapplication of `def` — use `let` instead.  You don't need `test1` to be a global variable — passing `test1` into `total-time` makes no sense, since `total-time` is where `test1` is defined!  In fact, by passing `test1` into `total-time` you will effectively be redefining it as twice the original value.

I would also suggest you revisit your name selection of the 'actual-time' parameter.  It's not clear to me what is meant by "actual" time.  Isn't this the amount of time spent in the oven thus far?  Perhaps `oven-time` would be a less ambiguous name.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `def` inside `defn`. If you really need some variables, you can use [`let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let), but this exercise can be completed without it:

```
(ns lucians-luscious-lasagna)

(def expected-time 40)

(defn remaining-time [actual-time]
  (- expected-time actual-time))

(defn prep-time [num-layers]
  (* num-layers 2))

(defn total-time [num-layers actual-time]
  (+ (prep-time num-layers) actual-time))
```